# Storyboard TableViewController vs coded TableViewController cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xcode6

I'm pretty new to iOS dev so please bear with me.

I created a simple app that had a TabBarController with 2 items. The first item was a TableViewController with some cells and the 2nd item was a simple UIView with a picture and some text. Everything worked just fine in the simulator. This was all done programmatically (did not use storyboard)

I wanted to practice using the storyboard so I decided to try and replicate the original program I made using a storyboard. The problem arises when created a TableViewController. It's asking me to specify a "reuse identifier" , at first I tried naming them all "cell" but it said I couldn't use the same identifier, so then I set the first one to "cell1" and the next to "cell2" and so on.. I didn't have to do this when I wrote the app with just code, so why now?

My coded TableViewController looks like:

```
@implementation FeedTableViewController

- (id)init //constructor
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.title = @"Feed";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Title"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Title"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

in the last method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I just named them all "title" and it ran fine.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What do you mean by "them all"? How many cells do you have in the storyboard? You should only have one, if you only need one type of cell.

Comment: @rdelmar Them all refers to the cells, sorry. In that function I mentioned on the bottom of the post, I believe that I just named every cell "Title", because isn't that function used to initialize every cell?

Comment: But how many prototype cells did you have in your storyboard? You said you named them cell1, cell2, etc, so you must have had more than one.

Comment: Well, that's the difference between the two methods. You should only have one cell in the storyboard to mimic the one you have in code. the number of cells you have in the storyboard has nothing to do with the number of rows you see in the table view.